# Remove the users from /etc/ssh/sshd_config with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to remove users added to the AllowGroups line in the /etc/ssh/sshd_conf file using the following after the comments from @imjoseangel.

The current line is 
  AllowGroups devops1 devops2 devops3 user01 user02 user03
The desired line is 
  AllowGroups devops1 devops2 user02 user03
The play is

```
 name: Remove User from AllowGroups (opening dash removed)
 replace: 
  regexp: "(^AllowGroups)\\s.*" 
  backup: True 
  path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak 
  replace: "\\1 {{ item }} " 
 with_items: 
 - devops3 
 - user01
```

After the play is complete I am getting the following 
   "AllowGroups user01"

The whole is replaced by last user in the "item".

Comment: Maybe you can improve formatting your question. So help reading and answering.

Comment: I tried initially, however, after the post it became a paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked.

```
 tasks:
 - name: Remove User from AllowGroup and AllowUsers
   replace:
    regexp: "{{ item }}"
    backup: True
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak
    replace: "\b"
   with_items:
   - devops1
   - user03
```

Comment: Of course that will work, but how do you control if devops1 or user03 is in another line too?